# how match 2 columns of two dataframe based on their 2 first letter?

Tags: python, pandas

How I can pair columns of 2 data frames with the following assumption:

If the first 2 letters of `col1` in `df1` is the same as the first 2 leeters of `col2` in `df2` match.

```
df1:

col1
'summer'
'good heather'
'sooner come'
'keep up great work'
'really'


df2:
col2
'nice to be'
'good'
'remember'
'recall me'
```

output

```
col1                col2
'good heather'     'good'
'really'          'remember'
'really'          'recall me'
```

I have a big data set and looking for efficient method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
col1 = pd.DataFrame(
    ['summer',
'good heather',
'sooner come',
'keep up great work',
'really'])

col2 = pd.DataFrame([
    'nice to be',
'good',
'remember',
'recall me'
])
col1["first"] = col1[0].str[:2]
col2["first"] = col2[0].str[:2]
res = pd.merge(col1, col2, how='cross')
res[res['first_x'] == res['first_y']][["0_x", "0_y"]].reset_index(drop=True)
```

output:

```
    0_x             0_y
1   good heather    good
2   really          remember
3   really          recall me
```

**EDIT: without cross:**

```
import pandas as pd
col1 = pd.DataFrame(
    ['summer',
'good heather',
'sooner come',
'keep up great work',
'really'])

col2 = pd.DataFrame([
    'nice to be',
'good',
'remember',
'recall me'
])
col1["first"] = col1[0].str[:2]
col2["first"] = col2[0].str[:2]


left = col1.assign(key=1)
right = col2.assign(key=1)
res = left.merge(right, on='key').drop('key', axis=1)
res[res['first_x'] == res['first_y']][["0_x", "0_y"]].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: there is no key called `cross` for merge function

Comment: @user15649753 which pandas version do you use? And please add error message exactly...

Comment: KeyError: 'cross'

Comment: @user15649753 your pandas version is old... please update it

Comment: @user15649753 or, use edit part in post